# How to install ubuntu without losing data in other drives?

Tags: system-installation

I have 3 drives C, D, E.

I've got windows 7 installed in the C drive.

How do I install Ubuntu without losing data in the D and E drives?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: do not format those 2 partitions.

Mark down the sizes of the partitions so you can confirm it during installation. D: is likely to be named sda2 and E: probably sda3 in Ubuntu/during install. C: will be sda1.
That is if these are on the 1st hard disc. If you have 2 discs 'a' will be 'b' (and so on).

But of course you do make a backup of anything important.